# CMD: Parametrization of a for-variable

Tags: for-loop, cmd, batch-processing

I have a for loop executed by **CMD.exe**, the so called "windows command processor".
It executes from a batch file, not in the box.
Now I want to look for file names that contains a certain pattern and search expression and then do some processing to it, which is out of the scope of this question.
So I use the **/F switch** of the **for loop** and make use of the "parsingkeywords" `tokens` and `delims`.
Currently the parameter values for 'tokens' and 'delims' are hard coded and the loop is constructed this kind:

```
for /F "tokens=1-4 delims=-._" %%A in ('dir /b .\%_SEARCH%') do @if exist "%dir_PROCESSED%\*%%~D*" call :check_size "%%~D"
```

Now what I'd like to achieve is to parametrize both of these values. OK that's easy.
 Just use a parameter or an environment variable, like

```
for /F "tokens=%_tokens% delims=%_delims%" %%A in ('dir /b .\%_SEARCH%') do if exist "%_dir_PROCESSED%\*%%~D*" call :check_size "%%~D"
```

But what in consequence has to be parametrized also, is the loop-variable which is currently `%%D`, but which depends on the tokens count and the position of the element of interest in the search pattern.
And how can I parametrize the Loop-Variable?
How can I use an environment-variable to be expanded to a Loop-Variable
For example if I wanted the first token, I would use `%%A`.
What would be the right syntax to make the loop variable letter itself an environment variable?
This does not work:

```
    set _LOOPVAR=A
    for /F "tokens=%_tokens% delims=%_delims%" %%A in ('dir /b .\%_SEARCH%') do if exist "%_dir_PROCESSED%\*%%~%_LOOPVAR%*" call :check_size "%%~%_LOOPVAR%"
```

Err-Message is (translated GER to ENG):

```
"The following usage of the Pathoperator for replacing the a batch parameter is invalid: %~nxA"
```

I know it can be done with `cmd /c` a/o `call` but I don't get the right syntax and namely the count of percentage-chars ;)

Any help  and support welcome...

Answer (score 0):

In case some one will be interested in this or a similar scenario now or in the future. The solution is as simple as can be. The first assumption that the for-variable or loop-variable of a for or especially for /F loop with cmd.exe cannot be indirectly set by an environment variable is simply wrong.

CMD.exe batch code like:

```
set tokens=1-4
set delims=-._
set loopvar=B
for /F "tokens=%tokens% delims=%delims%" %%A in ('dir /s /b %whatever%') do echo %%~%loopvar%
```

seems fully functional and valid.